# Change nginx default folder

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, deployment

Here what I have done:

1/ Use Google cloud as a server (Ubuntu 18) for admin page.

2/ Have a project react-js app, ex: abc

3/ Encrypt website [www.sub.abc.com](http://www.sub.abc.com) successfully, point to IP (Godday domain) on Google cloud successfully. (Source: https://linuxhint.com/redirecting_http_https/).

Problem: My app can not run on port 80, nginx took it! I have search many instructions but they
are not clear.

What I have done to fix this:

1/ Edit config file of nginx (https://www.tecmint.com/change-nginx-port-in-linux/).

2/ Export port 80 in my app. (export port=80 npm start).
Can not run my app on port 80 because something has taken that port?!
If I kill port 80 ===> nginx turn off.

Please give me the right way to change config file or replace nginx default folder to my app folder. Thank you!

---

I have deployed successfully. If you have the same problem. Can follow this.

DEPLOY

NPM + NODEJS

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash -
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

NGINX

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install nginx
```

CONFIG

```
cd /
sudo mkdir app
sudo mkdir api
sudo mkdir html <=== git clone ...
cd /etc/nginx/conf.d
sudo touch api.conf 
sudo vi api.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the nginx as reverse proxy and change the port of you app for another like 8000 for example and configue in nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
}
```

---

I have deployed successfully.
If you have the same problem. Can follow this.

DEPLOY

```
`$ sudo apt-get install curl
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash -
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs`
```

NGINX

```
`$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install nginx`
```

CONFIG

```
`cd /
sudo mkdir app
sudo mkdir api
sudo mkdir html <=== git clone ...
cd /etc/nginx/conf.d
sudo touch api.conf 
sudo vi api.conf`
```

Comment: Hi @Vagner Franco. It show "Bad gate".

Image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7f3c6o6l9mgupx/config-ssh-ubuntu.png?dl=0